# How to call public function in separate file? zend - postgre

Tags: php, json, postgresql, zend-framework

```
<?php
    require('Zend/Db.php');
    Class TampilJson {
        protected $_db;
        public function _koneksi () {
            try {
                $this->_db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_PGSQL', array(
                    'host'       => 'localhost',
                    'username'   => 'postgres',
                    'password'   => 'sssda',
                    'dbname'     => 'zend',
                ));
                return $this->_db;
            } catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function getData () {
            $db = $this->_koneksi();
            try {
                $sql = "select * from biodata";
                $data = $db->fetchAll($sql);
                return $data;
            } catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    $view = new TampilJson();

    $biodata = $view->getData();
    echo json_encode($biodata);
?>
```

I want to create tree file from that code(connect.php, getdata.php, jsonview.php) but public function can't be called from the other file. I use the "require" but it doesn't make any different. Can anybody help me with this code?
thanks.